# Apply Style to a div class in B2b LWR site

Tags: css, b2b-commerce, lwr

I need to add style property to a div class in LWR site.I am adding Style = "position:relative". How can i specify this override in Css head markup of the Site?

[image: Div class]

[image: Head Markup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where there isn't a CSS property, you can resort to using a [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) - many patterns are supported.

For your case that could be:

```
<style>
div[name="header"].header {
    position: relative !important;
}
</style>
```

Try without the [!important](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) first.

Comment: Thanks Keith it worked. Cant we simply specify .className{position: relative;} here?

Comment: Hi @DeepakAgarwal, Yes you can try any CSS selector you like, just best to make it as specific as possible and avoid class names that may be generated on the fly such as `lwc-4g...` one.